# Results of PHP file to HTML page

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I have a contact form (from the internet)

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<<< FORM >>>>
<input type="submit" value="Verstuur">
</form>
```

After that, it goes to the html_form_send.php

With some messages, when you succes or an error for example:

```
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
   }
```

It works great, only I want the message (The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid) on the first html page (./contact.html) under the form. How do I do this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: send header with an extra url parameter  http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML forms don't take any sort of callback for when they're finished, but one approach that you could try is redirecting back to the contact.html with a GET variable that alerts the page that your email address is malformed.

For example, on contact.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] == "emailerror") {
        echo "<p>The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.</p>";
    }
?>
```

and on html_form_send.php,

```
if(!preg_match(...)) {
    header('location: contact.html?msg=emailerror');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="htmlform" name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<<< FORM >>>>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

in a script

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 $("#htmlform").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   $.post( "html_form_send.php", function( data ) {
       var frm =  $("#htmlform");
       var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
      $( ".result" ).html( data );
   });//post

 });//form

});//ready
```

reference http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/